# How to loop script

Tags: jquery, loops, checkbox, slider

I'm trying to make script, that works like step by step slider with a period of clicks. The main goal was to make LABEL be the trigger of that clicks. I made the script, but how to make it work with loop: when it reaches the last LABEL it goes to first in cycle? Any help? 
http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/ojBmXM

```
$('label').each(function(i, e) {
  var delay = 1000;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('label').removeClass('button-checked');
    $(e).trigger("click").addClass('button-checked');

  }, i * delay);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
function changeTo(i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("label").removeClass('button-checked');       
        $("label:eq(" + i%4 + ")").trigger("click").addClass('button-checked');
        changeTo(i+1);  
    }, 1000);       
}
changeTo(0);
```

EDIT (Answer to follow-up question):

```
var loop = true;

function changeTo(i) {      
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (loop) {
            $("label").removeClass('button-checked');       
            $("label:eq(" + i%4 + ")").trigger("click").addClass('button-checked');
            changeTo(i+1);  
        }
    }, 1000);
}
changeTo(0);

$(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=sec-1]').click(function() {
        loop = false;
        $("label").removeClass('button-checked');
        $(this).prev("label").addClass('button-checked');
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanx! 
and one more question: if I click LABEL how to stop this script?

Comment: Great job! Thank you very much! You helped me alot! Cheers!

**UPD Oh, and if we dont know how many elements of labels? **

Comment: $("label").length will give you the amount of elements that match the selector.

Comment: Aha! ok. Thanks alot again!